# Roots of $x^3-2=0$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: galois-theory

My professor mentioned during lecture that the roots of $x^3-2=0$ over  $\mathbb{Q}$  are $\sqrt[3]{2}, j\sqrt[3]{2}, j^2\sqrt[3]{2}$, where $j$ is a root of $x^2+x+1$.

I would like some clarification on the connection between the roots of  $x^3-2=0$ and the roots of $x^2+x+1$. What is the significance of $x^2+x+1$ and why do two of the roots of the irreducible polynomial $x^3-2=0$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ depend on it?

How does the polynomial $x^2+x+1$  change when we consider roots of irreducible polynomials of higher degree? (i.e. $x^n-k=0$ for $n,k \in \mathbb{Z}$)

Thank you

Comment: $(x-1)(x^2+x+1) = x^3-1$. The point is that $j$ is a cube root of unity which is different from $1$.

Comment: Over $\mathbb Q$? I don't understand $-$ none of those roots are in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @TonyK the polynomial is over the rationals, and not over say the field with $5$ elements..

Comment: @quid: So all it's saying is that the coefficients $1$ and $-2$ are to be interpreted as rational numbers? Whereas the roots are allowed to be in $\mathbb C$? That to me is a strange use of the phrase "the roots of $f$ over $\mathbb Q$".

Comment: @TonyK I agree that the precise wording is not optimal. But the wording that $P$ is a polynomial over the ring $R$ is a common one.

Comment: @TonyK Well, the roots are allowed to be the splitting field of $x^3-2$, a subset of the algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q$. It happens to be that that's a subset of $\Bbb C$, which is fortunate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a square free integer $a$ the solutions to $X^p-a$ are $b\zeta^k$ for $0 \leq k \leq p-1$  where $\zeta$ is a primitive p-th root of unity and $b$ is the p-th root of $a$. 
So in this case $b=\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\zeta$ is a primitive 3rd root of unity.